# Python multiprocessing: memory management Linux vs OSX

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, macos

Please see the following snippet of code:

```
for par_run in range(20):
   pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
   res = pool.map(func_parallel, mp_args)
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
```

Here `mp_args` is passing the `func_parallel` huge matrices (1million * 10)
I expect the above code snippet to cause a memory leak and ultimately crash with "Memory Error" as it does on Linux (Ubuntu 14).

on Ubuntu

```
watch -n 1 "free | grep Mem| awk '{print \$4/\$2 * 100.0}'"
```

Shows that the free memory is used up.

However on OSX

```
watch -n 1 "top -l 1 -s 0 | grep PhysMem"
```

Shows: `PhysMem: 16G used (3533M wired), 16M unused.`
And does not crash.

How is memory management different in OSX than in Ubuntu that the same piece of code does not crash?

Configuration:

OSX:: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 8cores

Ubuntu BOX:: 30GB 8cores

Comment: Your linux box has less memory? It's hard to reproduce any of this from what you've provided, or even estimate how much memory this would use. '1 million * 10' what?

Comment: It actually has more memory. 30 GB, 1 million *10 is the matrix size, numpy array, edited the question added configurations as well

Comment: a numpy array of what? Can you write a [MCVE] of this? If these matrices were a 100 megs a piece it's not clear why this should run out of memory at all. Have you checked limits? It's much more likely this about the details of your program and setup than something about the memory management of linux and os x.